# Agent Side checkout reverting to Server Side Checkout for Perforce Stream Depot

Tags: teamcity

Running 2020.1.1 (build 78657)

I have a VCS root for a Perforce Stream Depot (with the option to Enable feature branches support).

I also have several builds with Version Control Settings having **VCS checkoutmode** set to **Prefer to checkout files on agent**.

However, I am seeing these messages in the build logs:

`[Updating sources] Will use server side checkout: Checkout rules are not supported for vcs root 'StreamRoot'. Details: Perforce stream checkout on agent supports only one single include rule like . => sub/directory, requested rule: +:area/functions/functionsA => .`

This message is confusing to me, because I only have a single checkout rule (as shown in the log):
`+:area/functions/functionsA => .`

I would appreciate any insight from the community.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is the message isn't so descriptive. I've also come across this problem, and seems it only works when specifying a single rule that applies to the whole stream, e.g. `+:. => some/path`